# Laravel 403 Forbidden: You do not have permission to access this document

Tags: php, laravel

I'm able to upload files normally on my Laravel panel but I get:
Server Error 403 Forbidden: You do not have permission to access this document.
When I try to view the file.

Here is my .htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

filesystems.php

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Please someone help, I'm trying to solve this issue since a while, I checked files permissions and all seems to be okay, So maybe someone can point out the cause of the error?

Answer (score -4):

As the error says `Server Error 403 Forbidden: You do not have permission to access this document` your webserver doesn't have a right to write in the directory.

You can follow these steps in order to give permissions in your laravel project.

[Securely setting file permissions for Laravel Framework](https://vijayasankarn.wordpress.com/2017/02/04/securely-setting-file-permissions-for-laravel-framework/)